# update the column values in csv file if it contains a string matches INC** using powershell scripts

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a scenario where I need to write replace the column values if it contains INC** number instead of entire value

```
Duration    starttime       task
3 hours     24-09-2020      @{display_value=INC*****6; link=https://8888.service-8888888888888}
8 hours     23-09-2020      @{display_value=INC*****7; link=https://8888.service-888888888888888}
```

Now in task column I have to fill this by

**task
INC*****6
INC*****7**

Actually I got this csv file by accessing servicenow apis and converted the payload to csv file using powershell script. Can someone guide me

Comment: "I got this csv file by accessing servicenow apis and converted the payload to csv file using powershell script" - can you show us the script that produced the file? This will be _much easier_ to do _before_ serializing the data to disk

Answer (score 1):

It will be easiest to edit the `INC######` value when you receive the payload from the API as a PowerShell object.

```
$payload.task.display_value = $payload.task.display_value -replace '\d(?=\d)','*'
```

---

If you must use this CSV file, which should be unnecessary, you will have to do some parsing:

```
# I assumed the delimiter/separator is a tab. Change it to the appropriate character if needed.
$csv = import-csv file.csv -delimiter "`t"
foreach ($row in $csv) {
    $row.task = $row.task -replace '(?<=display_value=INC\d*)\d(?=\d)','*'
}
$csv | Export-Csv output.csv -delimiter "`t"
```

---

See [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/Twc9xi/1) for regex explanation.